# Weighted MLE for more accurate fitting of extreme values?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, modeling

I want to fit a 3-component exponential mixture distribution to some data that's clearly over-dispersed relative to the standard exponential.

Regular MLE works reasonably well, but it doesn't model the most extreme observed values that well.  As the values get larger, I care more about the accuracy of the fit, so I was thinking a good solution would be to weight the fit the values themselves.

E.g., the penalty for misfitting an observed value of 50 should be 10x larger than for misfitting 5.

Is it possible to overlay a weighting like this ontop of regular MLE?

Comment: Is it possible your likelihood function is the wrong function?

Comment: Wrong?  It's a model.. so any distribution is just an approximation of reality.  I could add more components to the mixture, but 3 components is as complex as I'd like to go.

Comment: I think you need to add more details.  "doesn't model the most extreme observed values that well" and "penalty for misfitting an observed value" are a bit vague.  Fitting is usually judged by long-term properties rather than how it works with a particular set of data (if you're a Frequentist).  But if you want a Bayesian approach, have you seen https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e603/46eb2579803496898950982dd4e5cd5d8c60.pdf ?

Comment: Thanks, that paper led me to read more about Bayes estimators and loss functions, but I'm not sure they're generic enough.  To clarify, the problem with my fit is that the 99.9th percentile is 3x too low relative to the observed quantiles. So ideally a Bayes loss function would measure the posterior quantiles of the fitted distribution, but I don't think that's feasible.